# Design Pattern for android

Tags: android, design-patterns

Today I came across a Interview where I was put this question, **"What design pattern do you follow?"**. Can anyone explain me about this. I am totally blank here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess the interviewer just wanted to know of the design patterns awareness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science) rather than it being something specific to android.

Comment: You could have just said: "Model View Controller" (or model-view-viewmodel to be precise). It is what Android is based on :D

Comment: @Scorpion: you have to close two brackets after URL

Comment: This question is better suited to the stackexchange programmers site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @MisterSquonk, who commented your question. Nevertheless: I would have said "I use the most suitable pattern". Even though @Maggie is also right in her comment about the "MVC" concept for Android, a mature programmer knows that there is no silver bullet in architecture. You have to pick your tools, models and design patterns with great care for each individual project.